# CorePlot iOS, plotting on the right date.

Tags: ios, graph, core-plot

I am having trouble plotting a sales graph "properly". I am getting the data from a webservice in json format. Below is an example of the data:
      {
        DataInfo = salesPerDay;
        parameter1 = "12/30/14";
        parameter2 = "222.00";
    },
        {
        DataInfo = salesPerDay;
        parameter1 = "12/02/14";
        parameter2 = "12312.00";
    }

My graph works fine except for the dates on the x-axis. Supposedly, the two scatter plot dots should be at (12/30/14, 222) and (12/02/14, 12312). however, I think it just graphs in the order it passes in so right now i have (12/30/14, 222) and (12/31/14, 12312) which is not accurate to what I want to plot.

Another issue I'm dealing with is that my graph starts at "x = -1" when it should start at the origin. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the date values to numbers before passing them to the plot. You can choose any conversion scheme you want as long as it is consistent. There is a demo in the *Plot Gallery* example app that shows one way to plot dates along an axis. The starting point of the x-axis is set by the `location` of the plot space's `xRange`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. But right now, data is sent in like below:
{
        DataInfo = salesPerDay;
        parameter1 = "11/13/13";
        parameter2 = "55.00";
    },
        {
        DataInfo = salesPerDay;
        parameter1 = "12/13/13";
        parameter2 = "65378796.00";
    },
and then after converting it into date values, the above data becomes:
        {
        0 = 0;
        1 = "55.00";
    },
        {
        0 = 86400;
        1 = "65378796.00";
    },

as you can see, dec 13 (second value) becomes nov 14 (the next value after the first) on the x axis

Comment: 0 = x values 
1 = y values

Comment: How are you converting the date values? Pick a date for your zero point and calculate the offset of each date value from that origin date. You can compute offsets in days, hours, seconds, or any other calendar unit that works for your app. Core Plot includes a couple of formatter classes that help format axis labels when working with dates this way.